# Print my values across instead of down

Tags: java

my values are printing

```
16 
25
36
```

I would like my code to print like this

```
16 25 36
```

How do I achieve this? do I manipulate my `println();` or do I need to change my entire code?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int start = 4;

        int stop = 6;

        findX(start, stop);
    }

    public static void findX(int start, int stop) {
        int numbers;

        for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++) {
            numbers = i * i;
            System.out.println(numbers);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `print` instead of `println`. `ln` suffix represents line separator which will be added after printing your data.

Comment: Use print instead println. println adds new line to your output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.out.print(numbers + " ");`

`println` includes a newline at the end. `print` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
System.out.print(numbers + " ")
```

System.out.println adds a newline to the end of the output

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++){
    System.out.print(i * i + (i == stop ? "\n" : " "));
}
```

has an elegance to it, at the expense of checking (repeatedly, at least in concept) `i == stop`. It doesn't output a superfluous space, but outputs a newline character in its place.

Personally though, unless you're working on some high-end GUI project, I wouldn't fight the *natural* output, and leave things as they are.